# Multidimensional Array from HTML using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have repeating div's down a page. I need to select the outerbox ID's and text  element

```
<div class="outerbox" id="12345">

        <div class="headerbox" id="title12345">

            <div class="text">&nbsp;</div>
            <h2>Foo Bar
            </h2>
        </div>
```

I need to create a multi-dimensional array using jquery

I have it this far with creating a single array for the outerbox ID's

```
var boxids = $('.outerbox').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
var boxidsLength = boxids.length;

var i = 0; i < boxidsLength; i++) {
    alert (boxids[i])
}
```

But I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the process of how 1) I'd create a multi-dimensional array from this input and how to 2) select the  element under class 'text'

The array would look like

```
Foo Bar | Bar Foo

12345   | 67890
```

etc

Thank you

Comment: If possible , can post literal `[[]]` of required array ? Not certain about description of result at _"The array would look like"_  `Foo Bar | Bar Foo` `12345   | 67890` ? `[id, text]` ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I understand two dimensional arrays as being laid out like a spreadsheet

[Foo Bar[1234] Bar Foo [4567]] would be the ideal output so I could call them as array[0][0] and get Foo Bar then array[0][1] to get 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
var boxids = $('.outerbox').map(function() { 
  return [[$.trim($(".text + *", this)[0].innerText), this.id]] ; 
}).get();
```

```js
var boxids = $('.outerbox').map(function() { 
  return [[$.trim($(".text + *", this)[0].innerText), this.id]] ; 
}).get();
$("body").text(boxids);
console.log(boxids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerbox" id="12345">

        <div class="headerbox" id="title12345">

            <div class="text">&nbsp;</div>
            <h2>Foo Bar
            </h2>
        </div>
    
    <div class="outerbox" id="67890">

        <div class="headerbox" id="title678905">

            <div class="text">&nbsp;</div>
            <h2>bar foo
            </h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: What am I missing when I have this box repeating? See

http://jsfiddle.net/z183gfpx/

Comment: Not certain what mean by "missing" ? `console.log(boxids[0][0], boxids[0][1], boxids[1][0], boxids[1][1]);` ?

Comment: If there are two instances of the 'outerbox' code above, one called foo bar and one called bar foo, with different IDs

I get [foo bar bar foo[12345][foo bar bar foo[67890]]

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
var array = [];
$('.outerbox').each(function ()
{
    var id = this.id;
    var text = $(this).find('.text').next().text();

    array[text] = id;
});
```

But maybe you need to sanitize the `text`, to trim spaces and line breaks.